# How to add values to a spreadsheet from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a template spreadsheet document that has two columns, Server Name and IP Address.
How can I populate the spreadsheet so that each dictionary key goes in its own cell in the Server column and the corresponding value goes in the cell next to it in the IP column?

I am using the EPPlus library but couldn't find anything on the topic.

Below is what I found and tried, but its for lists

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(_fileInfo))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfIPs.Count; i++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = listOfIPs[i];
    }

    package.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not familiar with EPPlus, therefore I am not sure how you get the reference to the active sheet - you need to figure out this bit though once that's done pure C# with a bit of knowledge about VBA model and you can easily **avoid any iterations** to get contents of your dictionary to a spreadsheet:

```
// create a sample dictionary and fill it
Dictionary<string, string> myCol = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myCol.Add("server1", "ip1");
myCol.Add("server2", "ip2");

// grab a reference to the active Sheet
// this may vary depending on what framework you are using
Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;

// create a Range variable
Range myRange;

// Transpose the keys to column A
myRange = ws.get_Range("A1");
myRange.get_Resize(myCol.Keys.ToArray().Count(),1).Value = 
                 ws.Parent.Parent.Transpose(myCol.Keys.AsEnumerable().ToArray());

// transpose the Values to column B
myRange = ws.get_Range("B1");
myRange.get_Resize(myCol.Values.ToArray().Count(), 1).Value = 
               ws.Parent.Parent.Transpose(myCol.Values.AsEnumerable().ToArray());
```

Debugging results as expected

[image]

---

With EPPlus I think you can do it like this (untested)

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test");

    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(myColl, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium);

    package.Save();
}
```

More details on VBA Collections iterations and printing to Sheet @ [**vba4all.com**](http://vba4all.com/how-to-write-a-vba-collection-andor-dictionary-scripting-dictionary-to-a-spreadsheet/)

Comment: Is there a way to `LoadFromCollection` where the dictionary has multiple values? When I try to load a dictionary that looks like this: `Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();` the values don't get inserted. I get this value in excel: `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`

Comment: @DesmondLost I am not really familiar with EPPlus but I wouldn't think that is possible...

Answer (score 2):

You can just access the keys of a dictionary and iterate over them just like you are iterating over the list.

```
        var foo = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // populate your dictionary
        foreach(var key in foo.Keys)
        {
            var value = foo[key];
            // do stuff with 'key' and 'value', like put them into the excel doc
        }
```

Comment: seriously? iteration? this is old school and much inefficient.